# LibreOffice: how to increment numbers based on conditions

Tags: formula, libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

I am struggling to write a formula in order to increment numbers only on certain conditions.

Lets say I have three columns (A,B,C) (Picture attached). Where Column A and B are pre-populated and Column C needs to be filled with a formula.

Such that, the number in column C should increment only if column B value changes, and it should be reset to 1 if column A value changes.

What I tried:

```
=IF(AND(A2=A1,COUNTIF(B:B,B2)=1),C1+1,1)
```

also:

```
C = 1
=IF(A1<>A2;1;IF(AND(A2=A1;B2=B1);C1;C1+1))
```

but failed to achieve the desired results, thank you for all the help. cheers

```
column A    column B    column C
10          4           1
10          4           1
10          3           2
10          3           2
20          5           1
20          4           2
20          4           2
30          9           1
30          7           2
40          6           1
40          5           2
40          5           2
40          3           3
40          2           4
```

EDIT:

I figured out the correct formula:

```
=IF(A3<>A2,1,IF(B3=B2,C2,C2+1))
```

Comment: Could someone please help in formatting the picture?

Comment: Instead of a picture, it's better to put spreadsheet values in formatted text in the question. That way, people can copy and paste them. EDIT: Indent to format the values. EDIT 2: Yes, it's good now. No need for the image anymore.

Comment: @JimK just did that, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second formula can be shortened.

```
=IF(A1<>A2;1;IF(B2=B1;C1;C1+1))
```

However, your version also produces the desired results. The question is, why did it not work for you? Perhaps you failed to drag the formula down to fill properly.

By the way, the formula with `COUNTIF(B:B)` does not work because it is true if the value is anywhere in the column, not only the next one.

Comment: I clicked on the lower right corner of the cell and dragged it down and it pasted only 1 in all the cells?

Comment: Strange. Perhaps you've found a bug. What version of LibreOffice? Also try selecting cells C2 to C14 and going to *Edit -> Sheet -> Fill Cells -> Fill Down*.

Comment: Here the columns are A,D,E instead of A,B,C

Comment: Perhaps some of your data is different from how it looks, for example, strings versus numbers. Start with a new file and reproduce the example exactly as stated in your question, and see if the same problem occurs.

Comment: Should I change the type to numbers in all the cells?

Comment: I copied the example from your question into a CSV file and then opened the file in LibreOffice. It worked correctly without any formatting. You could also start with a new file and enter the values. Note that `10` does not equal `'10`, that is, strings and numbers are not equal.

Comment: What version of LibreOffice? *Help -> About LibreOffice*. And it looks like that is Ubuntu.

Comment: Yes sir that is ubuntu. should that be a problem?

Comment: I just tried it online on google-sheet and it gives the same incorrect results.

Comment: the correct formula should have been: `=IF(A3<>A2,1,IF(D3=D2,E2,E2+1))` for that matter. I will accept your answer for helping! cheers :D